# Ruby exec "mysql -u root ... < some.sql" doesn't work

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, exec

In `ruby-1.8.7-p302` when I do

```
exec "mysql -u root --password=****** onc_test < support/submission.sql"
```

I get a sudden exit, whether I do it in Rails, Rails console, or IRB. I am running `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.53, for apple-darwin10.4.0 (i386) using readline 6.1`

Incidentally,

```
exec "mysqldump -u root --password=****** onc_test > support/submission.sql"
```

works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to speculate on maybe exec wrapping it around with something that breaks it

Have you tried using backticks?

```
`mysql -u root --password=****** onc_test < support/submission.sql`
```

Check that output

Comment: That works fine, but still not with exec. What could exec be wrapping it with?

Comment: According to this article, it seems that exec replaces the current ruby or rails process by that, and that causes some issues (I'm assuming).  Have you tried with Kernel::system instead? -- http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html

Comment: I misread your comment because it looks like code markup. For others who read this, the ruby system command needs to be wrapped in ` (backticks). exec will not work because it takes over the process image.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` is causing an immediate exit because that is what it does.  It immediately exits your ruby process. From Kernel doc on rubydoc:

> Replaces the current process by running the given external command.

Use backticks or `system` if you want to keep your ruby process alive.  As for your mysql import not working, try giving it the absolute path to your sql dump.

Comment: Yes, I was using an absolute path with Rails.root but I removed that when I tried it with plain ruby. Thanks for the answer, yours is also correct (sorry I can only pick one).